# Rails 3 with Liquid Custom Tags not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, liquid, custom-tag

I am trying to create a set of custom tags for some liquid templates using Rails 3.  I added a 'liquid_tags.rb' in my lib/ directory with content like this:

```
class UserControls < Liquid::Tag                                             
  def initialize(tag_name)
     super 
  end

  def render(context)
    tag = "<b>TAG</b>"
  end    
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('user_controls', UserControls)
```

When I try to get the tag in my view via '{% user_controls %}' it tells me the tag isn't found.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That's right, as marcusmateus says, Rails won't load anything in the lib directory automatically even if you have added it to the autoload_paths unless the class or module name inside the file matches the file name.

To sort this problem just put the custom formatters inside the lib directory, each in their own file (I tried using a module to wrap them all up but no luck)

```
  class MyCustomTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, params, tokens)
      # do something
    end

    def render(context)
      # do something
    end
  end
```

Then created an initializer (in config/initializers) responsible for registering the custom tags with Liquid. i.e.

```
Liquid::Template.register_tag('custom_tag', MyCustomTag)
Liquid::Template.register_tag('custom_tag', MyCustomTag2EtcEtc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that file is getting loaded?  If it's not, then register_tag is never getting called.  I would throw in a puts statement above register_tag to debug it, make sure that the file is actually being loaded.  You may to move the register_tag into an initializer

Comment: I suspected that might be a problem but I can't figure out why the file in the lib/ directory wouldn't get loaded.  There are other files in that directory that are getting loaded fine.

Comment: There have been some changes regarding the lib/ directory being loaded automatically with the rails 3 betas.  I had to add the lib directory to config/application.rb `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)`

Comment: this issue has some useful comments related to Jekyll GitHub pages ignoring plugins: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5265

Answer (score 1):

on config/application.rb try adding this line

```
config.autoload_paths << File.join(config.root, "lib")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not loading problem -- I have it also. The tag is being loaded, you can print the current registered tags:

```
Liquid::Template.tags.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe files are only autoloaded if the name of the file matches the name of the class it contains.  In the question you state that your file is named 'liquid_tags.rb', but your class is named UserControls... if you rename your filed 'user_controls.rb' it should begin autoloading.